# How to test login page signing on with 100 username, password and email from txt file or excel file using Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, authentication, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to test my website's login page. I will use selenium IDE on Firefox. I want Selenium to take datas my user_data.txt or user_data.xls files. 100 different username, email, password will be test.
How to test my website's login page that I want?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet in this scenario is to extend the IDE.

You can define a while loop, a username/password/email generator save it to a .js file and link to if from Options -> Selenium Core Extensions

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Selenium WebDriver to do this quite easily. I use Visual Studio 2010 and utilise the 'DataSource' attribute for my tests where you can specify a file (I use an MTM Test Case) and then access the test runs variables as you want.
To use an attribute you would want this above your test method:

```
[TestMethod, DataSource("parameters here")]
```

It would be good to read up on this before diving in to using it as it's very useful but should be planned in the context of what you are testing. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use some plugins to do this with Selenium IDE as well.
The plugin called DataDriven, which you can download here:  http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/datadriven

I use this plugin frequently to recurse a data file and use the records in an iterative Selenium IDE native script.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by following steps :

> 1. Import goto_sel_ide.js file in "Selenium Core extensions"
> 2. Create googlesearch.js file with following details var quote=new Array("Saab","Volvo","BMW","Ford","Maruti","Honda","Suzuki");
> 3. Import this googlesearch.js file in "Selenium IDE extensions".
> 4. Click on Ok button and Restart Selenium IDE and Write script as per below.
>
> store 0 looptimes  while storedVars.looptimes <= 3  storeEval
>   quote[storedVars.looptimes] searchKey  open http://www.google.com type
>   q ${searchKey} click btnG pause 2000  store
>   javascript{storedVars.looptimes++;}  endWhile

you need to add 100 user names in username.js file

Answer (score 0):

[SeLite](https://code.google.com/p/selite/wiki/ProjectHome) is the one that I use for this. You'd need to download it as well as SeLite SelBlocks Global, both of which can be found [here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/). Personally I use a json file rather than an excel spreadsheet, but I believe that this can work with an xml as well as a json. Failing that, [Mr Data Converter](http://shancarter.github.io/mr-data-converter/) is a very reliable tool at converting from xml to json.

The seLite SelBlocksGlobal is an enhancement to the original [SelBlocks](http://refactoror.wikia.com/wiki/Selblocks_Reference)so there should be further information here on the addon functionality